# Can we show error message in MB, regarding fileinput plugin using msgSizeTooLarge option

Tags: javascript, file-upload

Regarding the file input plugin(http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input).

Can we show file size error message in MB? There is an option to customise the error message but I couldn't find to show size in MB instead of KB.

> msgSizeTooLarge
>
> File "{name}" ({size} KB) exceeds maximum allowed upload size of
>   {maxSize} KB. Please retry your upload!

Any solution to show size in MB?

Answer (score 1):

Very tricky thing to do, because the [Bootstrap File Input](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput) plugin does not have such expanded functionality. But hey, everything can be done in Javascript!

In order to change the validation error message, you have to add a handler to the `fileuploaderror` event (*Maybe you'll have to catch some other errors depending on your needs and settings. For full error supported events, see [here](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input#error-events)*). Then format the `msgSizeTooLarge` option string to what we want. We need to give the `msgSizeTooLarge` a custom format with our string key names; for `{size}` it will be `{customSize}` and for `{maxSize}` it will be `{customMaxSize}`. The `msgSizeTooLarge` message will be like this:

```js
msgSizeTooLarge: 'File "{name}" (<b>{customSize}</b>) exceeds maximum allowed upload size of <b>{customMaxSize}</b>. Please retry your upload!'
```

To get the file size, you will use the `data` parameter passed to the `fileuploaderror` event and use the first file size `size = data.files[0].size`. For the `maxFileSize`, you just read the element data, which there are all of fileinputs' data stored `maxFileSize = $(this).data().fileinput.maxFileSize`. Now, we just create a simple function to convert bytes to the proper format, or you can even change it and force it to always show MB formated values. The `formatSize` function wil be something like this:

```js
formatSize = (s) => {
    i = Math.floor(Math.log(s) / Math.log(1024));
    sizes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
    out = (s / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(2) * 1 + ' ' + sizes[i];
    return out;
};
```

Then we use the `replace` function to replace our string keys, with the formated file sizes:

```js
msg = msg.replace('{customSize}', formatSize(size));
msg = msg.replace('{customMaxSize}', formatSize(maxFileSize * 1024 /* Convert KB to Bytes */));
```

The result error message will be something like this:

> File "Endless Dream.mp3" (**2.07 MB**) exceeds maximum allowed upload size of **2 MB**. Please retry your upload!

Finally, we use the `data.id` to change the `<li>` element error text to what we have now:

```js
$('li[data-file-id="'+data.id+'"]').html(msg);
```

The result message:

[image: Bootrstrap File Input Screenshot]

You can test my example [here](http://zikro.gr/dbg/html/bootstrap-fileinput/index.html). Maximum filesize is **2MB**.

**My full working javascript code**

```js
$("#file-1").fileinput({
    uploadUrl: '#', // you must set a valid URL here else you will get an error
    overwriteInitial: false,
    maxFileSize: 2048, // 2028 KB == 2 MB
    msgSizeTooLarge: 'File "{name}" (<b>{customSize}</b>) exceeds maximum allowed upload size of <b>{customMaxSize}</b>. Please retry your upload!'
}).on('fileuploaderror', function(event, data, msg) {
    var size = data.files[0].size,
        maxFileSize = $(this).data().fileinput.maxFileSize,
        formatSize = (s) => {
            i = Math.floor(Math.log(s) / Math.log(1024));
            sizes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
            out = (s / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(2) * 1 + ' ' + sizes[i];
            return out;
        };

    msg = msg.replace('{customSize}', formatSize(size));
    msg = msg.replace('{customMaxSize}', formatSize(maxFileSize * 1024 /* Convert KB to Bytes */));
    $('li[data-file-id="'+data.id+'"]').html(msg);
});
```