# bootstrap upload not working properly, it does actually display the size

Tags: javascript, jquery

trying to use the Upload, it is working but instead it is only showing me the customsize instead of actual mb size of the uploaded Image

This is the link i am following to make the code works

[Can we show error message in MB, regarding fileinput plugin using msgSizeTooLarge option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656132/can-we-show-error-message-in-mb-regarding-fileinput-plugin-using-msgsizetoolarg)

The problem with this code is

```
$("#file-1").fileinput({
    maxFileSize: 5000,
               browseLabel: 'Browse',
               showUpload: false,
               browseIcon: '<i class="icon-file-plus"></i>',
               uploadIcon: '<i class="icon-file-upload2"></i>',
               removeIcon: '<i class="icon-cross3"></i>',
               layoutTemplates: {
                  icon: '<i class="icon-file-check"></i>',
                  modal: modalTemplate
               },
               overwriteInitial: false,
               initialCaption: "No file selected",
               previewZoomButtonClasses: previewZoomButtonClasses,
               previewZoomButtonIcons: previewZoomButtonIcons,
               fileActionSettings: fileActionSettings,
    msgSizeTooLarge: 'File "{name}" (<b>{customSize}</b>) exceeds maximum allowed upload size of <b>{customMaxSize}</b>. Please retry your upload!'
}).on('fileuploaderror', function(event, data, msg) {
    var size = data.files[0].size,
        maxFileSize = $(this).data().fileinput.maxFileSize,
        formatSize = (s) => {
            i = Math.floor(Math.log(s) / Math.log(1024));
            sizes = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB'];
            out = (s / Math.pow(1024, i)).toFixed(2) * 1 + ' ' + sizes[i];
            return out;
        };

    msg = msg.replace('{customSize}', formatSize(size));
    msg = msg.replace('{customMaxSize}', formatSize(maxFileSize * 1024 /* Convert KB to Bytes */));
    $('li[data-file-id="'+data.id+'"]').html(msg);
});
```

when the upload size exceeds, it does not show the actual file size of the uploaded file and how much is allowed. It just displays this

`customMaxSize customSize`

the corrosponding html is like this

```
<input type="file" class="file-input " name="photo" id="file-1" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif,.JPG,.JPEG,.PNG,.GIF" data-overwrite-initial="false">
```

message appears like this

File "DSC_0083.JPG" ({customSize}) exceeds maximum allowed upload size of {customMaxSize}. Please retry your upload!

it does resolve the customSize and customMaxSize

here is the fiddle, i am just lost why it is not working

https://jsfiddle.net/5esb4mcv/1/

as i have added all the steps there to understand what is going on